# What is a qualitative description of energy?

Tags: energy, work, definition

In elementary physics courses one is taught that *energy is a measure of an object's ability to do work* (this in itself seems a little flaky as how does one then define exactly what "work" is, other than stating that when a force acting on an system causes a displacement of that system, then the force is said to have done work on the system, or resorting to a tautological statement that describes it in terms of energy?!). Then in more advanced courses this description usually becomes more abstract in as such that *energy is a conserved quantity attributed to a physical system*, or an emergent quantity as a natural consequence of time translation invariance of a physical system (via Noether's theorem).

My question is, though, what exactly is energy? Is it possible to give a qualitative description of what it is a measure of?

I have read through the answers given in [What's the real fundamental definition of energy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/59719/whats-the-real-fundamental-definition-of-energy) and although they are somewhat useful, I feel that they don't really answer my question in terms of whether we can give a qualitative statement of what energy is, by this I mean, for example, *velocity is a measure of the rate of change in position of an object per unit of time*, is there a similar statement that can be ascribed to energy (or momentum for that matter)?

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that energy isn't a *measure of* anything at all - it *is* a thing.  That's in the same way that matter isn't a measure of anything either.  Given that `E = mc²`, they are arguably different forms of the same thing.

You can describe energy in terms of what it can do - pushing things along in the case of doing work - but energy isn't a measurement like velocity is.  You can also measure how much of it you have, in the same way that you can measure the mass of a lump of matter.

If energy is a *thing*, then conservation of energy intuitively makes sense.  You can't make matter just disappear.  You can move it or turn it into a different form, but it's still there.  The same goes for energy.

*Aside*: the English language has distinct words for "matter" (the thing) and "mass" (the amount of the thing).  The terminology gets a bit woolly when describing energy.

Answer (score 0):

Energy is like money - what you have in your pocket is only one of its many forms. Both are abstract ideas convertible between many forms.