# What is the latest definition of energy?

Tags: energy

So I will probably be screwed blued and tattooed for many reasons,  wrong forum,  nebulous question, etc. ,but aside from all available definitions what is the latest thinking on "what IS energy "

Comment: Energy is a function of the properties of the system that defines its behavior.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/59719/whats-the-real-fundamental-definition-of-energy? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/288773/what-is-the-rigorous-quantitative-definition-of-the-concept-of-energy? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/373174/has-there-been-any-developments-on-what-energy-really-is?