# Is energy only an idea?

Tags: energy, terminology

Physicists say that energy is the ability to do work, and work is moving something against a force, like gravity. But what is energy? Is it something real? I know I will be criticised for using that word. But is it, maybe, something tangible? Or is it only an idea that we created to broadly name a phenomenon we observed? I could not find the answer as to what energy is!

Comment: Read [this](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_04.html) explanation by Feynman

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What Is Energy? Where did it come from?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3014/)

Comment: Is pushing a cart uphill a tangible idea? If you don't think so, maybe it's time to get a cart and push it uphill for a while...