# Does energy exist, or is it just a relationship between other fundamental things?

Tags: energy, definition

Could anyone tell me what energy really is? I searched for it, and some people said that energy doesn't exist physically and it is not fundamental, but it is a relationship between other fundamental things, and there is not energy by itself, so it should be related to something else.

So could anyone help me understand it?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3014/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 4):

"What energy is" is a philosophical question.  It turns out its impossible for science to talk about what "reality" is like, other than to say that science forms models which have an "energy" term in them and they seem to be pretty good predictors.  If you're interested in that line of reasoning, I highly recommend looking into the philosophy of science.

However, we can find energy as a meaningful thing in our models.  One of the foremost ways of modeling our reality for scientific purposes is in the idea of "[action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_(physics))."  The idea of action is formed from this question:

Given a path that a system may take from state 1 to state 2, what path does it take?  In other words, if someone throws a ball (state 1) and later someone catches it (state 2), what did it do along the way?

What we have noticed through decades (and even centuries) of observation is that you can phrase this as a minimization problem (more formally, a stationary problem, which is a wider concept, but minimization is easier to think about).  We noticed that you can define a function for a system, called the Lagrangian, such that if you integrate it across the entire path the system takes through time, it's at a minimum (at a stationary point, in the complete version).  This integration across all time is called the "action" for the path taken.  Interestingly, this function works for all configurations the problem might take on.  You can find an action describing that ball flying through the air which works not only for your thrower and catcher as they are, but a thrower and catcher anywhere on the field!

This is a very abstract concept, and it's okay if it doesn't make 100% sense when you first work with it.  But what makes it important was that we came to this concept of Action without invoking forces or energy, or any of those other terms.  We just pointed out that the paths objects take tend to be the one which minimizes action across the entire path.  Or, more generally, we determined that you *could* find a Lagrangian for which the "correct" path is always found by solving this optimization problem that minimizes the action.  Actually figuring out a Lagrangian function which does this is another matter, what matters is that one exists!

Now should you accept this declaration that there always exists a Lagrangian function such that the correct path of objects is always found by minimizing the action?  Perhaps not.  Don't take my word for it.  Science is an empirical art, not a purely mathematical art.  It's the observation of scientists over the centuries that say "We can always describe the motion of particles this way!"

Now once you have this, we then can invoke one of the most powerful mathematical formalisms in all of physics: [Nother's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem).  This theorem shows that if you have a system which is described by this optimization problem, this minimization of action, and it has a continuous symmetry, then there is some conserved value.  This is neat because it takes some very abstract mathematical concepts, like continuous symmetries and action, and ties it directly to the idea of conserved values.

One continuous symmetry that's very important to physicists is time symmetry.  Basically that says that the laws of physics don't change over time.  We're only looking at laws that stay constant forever, from the big bang to however we end.  The laws of physics being the same at all times is formally termed as "time symmetry."  If you do something at one time, or do it 5 seconds later, the laws of physics will be the same in both cases.

This continuous time symmetry must have an associated conserved value, by Nother's theorem.  We call that conserved value "energy."  And if you actually go through all the fancy Calculus of Variations, you find that the thing that we conserve when we conserve energy is precisely what we told you was "energy" all along.

So, down in the weeds, that's the neat nature of energy.  Energy is the thing that must be conserved if the laws of physics are immutable over time.

Comment: Cort, I really like your approach. An explanation of energy should not be such as to scare someone from learning and thinking more about it.

Answer (score 3):

Well, maybe it's not important to know what energy is, as much as it is to know what energy can do. The typical definition of energy is that energy is the capacity to do work. If something has energy, it has the capacity to move things, lift things, heat things, and so forth. The other thing that is important to know is that energy can never be "created" or "destroyed". In other words, total energy is always conserved. It simply morphs into different forms as it is transferred between things in the form of either heat or work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But in General Relativity energy is not conserved, right? So saying it can't be created or destroyed might be slightly misleading.

Comment: @SV I don't know that that is correct. It's my understanding it is an open question. Wiki on the subject states "In general relativity, energy-momentum conservation is not well-defined except in certain special cases". It concludes with the statement "The theory of general relativity leaves open the question of whether there is a conservation of energy for the entire universe". As far as I am aware, Einstein himself didn't reach that conclusion. In any event I don't believe it is "misleading" to omit something that is largely a matter of conjecture, as with so many things in cosmology.

Comment: I believe this idea arises from the fact that the universe appears to be expanding with a virtually constant energy density (necessary for spacetime to be flat), but this does face the problem of whether the universe is infinite or not.

Answer (score 2):

I think term energy has slightly different meanings in different branches of physics. I prefer to think of it as the quantity that is conserved due to time-invariance of the equations of motion, i.e. my notion of energy is related to the Largangian mechanics (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics), and energy is basically the Hamiltonian.

Comment: +1 because I like the idea of symmetry. But it might be too advanced for the OP in this case.

Comment: Also, as far as I know energy is not a conserved quantity in General Relativity. But we still use it there.

Comment: I must say that my GR is not as good as I would like it to be, but I am ok with SR. What I like there, in SR, is that energy can be obtained from some basic arguments about the Lagrangian and Noethers Theorem. Same trick works in electromagetism.

Comment: I'm sorry, but can someone please point out in which branch of physics that energy has a different meaning? 

Also, the Hamiltonian of a system will not be its energy in the case of open systems, velocity dependent potentials, or time dependent coordinate systems.

Comment: Different meaning: I would imagine most applied disciplines may care less about time-invariance and more about the actual equation. Example, I would expect optical scientists, to talk about the optical energy density in the as ($\epsilon_0E^2/2+B^2/(2\mu_0$) even when there are non-linear effects that break time-invariance (e.g. a signal beam will not experience time-invariant environment if there is a strong pump-beam changing the refractive index of the medium). Sure this is not quite correct, but amongst themselves these scientists will know what is going on.

Comment: In case of open systems, AFAIK, energy (of the subsystem) is not conserved, but Hamiltonian may still be defined in some way (given time-invariance). So it makes sense to stick with it. Not sure about the velocity dependent potentials. The only example I know of is charged particles in electromagnetism. However there you would not consider the energy of just the particle. No, you would consider particle + field. Would that Hamiltonian not be the full energy?

Comment: @Cryo Judging by the OP question, I don't believe the OP is at a level to understand all this and that it helps to get a basic understanding which is what the OP needs. Conservation of energy is a law that has not, as yet, been shown to be violated. I still believe this is all in the realm of  conjecture.

Comment: @ Bob D. Perhaps there has been a misunderstanding. My previous comment was for @user400188. Was your comment about that or my original answer?

Comment: @S V There is a beastly [stress-energy-momentum pseudotensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy%E2%80%93momentum_pseudotensor) which is conserved for the same reasons energy is conserved in less exotic systems.

Answer (score 0):

Energy doesn't exist itself, it's just a mathematical representation to make a relationship between the capacity of several objects to develop work. I can make an analogy. Energy is like money, doesn't have value itself, it only represents the value of things (work, savings, estates, ...)

Comment: You have moved the definition from 'energy' to 'work'. What is 'work' then? How would you define ground-state energy, of, say, hydrogen atom with work?