# Constant Internal energy of universe and its original source

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, cosmology, astronomy

While  I was studying thermodynamics I am confused about internal energy of universe.   here a question confused me. "If the internal energy of the universe is constant then where did all energy come from originally?"
I would like to thank the person who explained it to me
thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What Is Energy? Where did it come from?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3014/)

Comment: I found them not enough

Comment: I need additional explanations