# Where does an object get its energy from and what does it mean?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, potential-energy

It is stated that an object in motion acquires "kinetic energy" while an object under the influence of gravity when raised to a height acquires "potential energy" but I have a doubt that what leads to the object acquiring the energy in actual sense?

What special is happening that an object in motion or an object at a height acquires the ability to do some work(i.e. energy)? If I start thinking about it more energy is just an "abstract thing" so is it just that we assign this value to an object under a specific condition and we say that it "gains" this energy? Also, isn't this energy just a "numerical value" with no real meaning so what is it even representing under a specific condition of motion or change in height?

P.S. I tried searching for similar questions on the internet and Physics S.E but couldn't find a  satisfactory answer yet.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3014/what-is-energy-where-did-it-come-from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most helpful thing to tell you here is that energy is not *a stuff*, not in the ordinary sense. Let me give you two definitions of stuff-ness:

1. Draw any imaginary box in space. Everyone agrees on the quantity of stuff inside that box, and it doesn't change arbitrarily, but mostly just by stuff going through the boundary of the imaginary box.
2. Draw an imaginary box im space, different people disagree on the amount of stuff in the box but everyone agrees on changes and how much stuff flows through the boundary.

All 1-stuffs are 2-stuffs automatically, it's a looser definition. Think of an example, toys in your niece's toy bin are a 1-stuff, everyone agrees in principle on the count of toys in that bin, we may have uncertainties about it or might happen to be in the wrong position to see into the toy bin. But the number of toys is some objective $N$ that hopefully we could all agree on.

Contrast this with the amount of forward momentum inside a train compartment. This is a 2-stuff. Everybody agrees that to change it you need to change a velocity, and all reference frames agree on changes in velocity. However the absolute amount of forward momentum appears to be near zero to someone who is inside the train and sees everybody sitting at rest, but appears to be very large to someone who is watching the train pass by from the ground.

There is no harm in pretending that a 2-stuff is a stuff as long as we remember that not every reference frame agrees on the total amount of stuff in the box, it is more than, as you say, “a numerical value with no real meaning” as it tracks with the stuff going through the boundary. So in the momentum case, these changes in momentum flowing out of the train compartment, correspond to a Newton's third law Force-pair where one of the objects is inside the train and the other one is outside. And what could be more "real meaning" than a force like that? An irregularity in the tracks knocks you and everybody else off their feet: surely that has real meaning!

Well, energy is precisely this sort of 2-stuff. Consider $N$ masses $m_i$ with velocities $v_i$ in the center of mass frame $\sum_i m_i v_i = 0,$ so in the center of mass frame the momentum is zero and the energy is in general nonzero, it is $$K = \frac12 \sum_i m_i v_i^2.$$ If I am traveling at velocity $u$ relative to this frame I see a kinetic energy
$$K' = \frac12 \sum_i m_i (v_i-u)^2 = K + \frac12 M u^2$$ where $M = \sum_i m_i$. In other words I see the center of mass kinetic energy plus a constant. Since no internal process of that cluster of particles will change $M$ or $u$, every energy difference that the center of mass frame sees, I also see. Furthermore energy is conserved, so it is a 2-stuff proper.

But, everyone is measuring the amount of work the system could do if it were elastically brought to absolute rest in their frame of reference, this is, as the above expression says, equal to the work to bring the system to rest in its center of mass frame plus the work to bring the center of mass frame to rest in my frame, $\frac12 M u^2.$ We all disagree because we disagree on this value.

It is something like if each toy in the toy bin had a little price tag on it and we measured the box by what was really important to us, which is the amount of value we can get by selling all of these toys, but we all had a different corporate bonus that we would get if we managed to sell the toy bin itself, which is only possible if you sell all of the toys in it. It is an imperfect analogy but maybe it helps. Those dollars are real, in this weird hypothetical they correspond to money that would be in my bank account at the end of the day, makes a very real difference to me. But the actual amount is different for different people looking at the same toy bin.

I hope that helps to see why differences in energy are "real" and energy itself is helpful even if subjective because it helps us get to the real things.

Answer (score 1):

When you lift an object against a gravitational field, the object itself is not acquiring the potential to do work- the gravitational field does work on the ball, and the higher you raise the object in the presence of the field, the more work (ie the more distance the field has to act as a force on the object) the field can do on the object.

You make a good observation that the potential energy is just a numerical value with no intrinsic meaning - we can set the "0" value of potential energy wherever we want. What does have meaning however is the *differences* in energies. Regardless of where I set my 0 of potential energy to be, whether it be at the Earth's surface or the ISS, the change in potential energy from a certain drop or increase in height will always be the same. This is consistent with the notion that the speed of the ball, assuming ideal conditions, is only dependent on the height at which the object is dropped with respect to the surface, ie a difference in height.

Comment: So what I deduced from this answer is that we have set a reference point of ground as having zero potential energy and as an object is increasing its height this numerical value of potential energy is assigned to an object (which is governed by the formula -mgh). So does this apply to kinetic energy as well? Like the zero point mark of kinetic energy is defined as zero relative motion and as an object increases its relative motion w.r.t to an observer the numerical value of kinetic energy is assigned to the object(also governed by a formula -1/2mv²).

Comment: Yes, the kinetic energy is also coordinate-dependent, and we can add an arbitrary fixed number to 1/2mv^2, say 5, and this is also a valid kinetic energy. Why "1/2mv^2" itself is significant is that it is the thing, in summation with potential energy as described, that is conserved during motion (and thus so is 1/2mv^2 + 5 plus the potential energy).

Answer (score 0):

See when a body against the gravitational field is present & no external force helps itself in lifting itself way up in the field so some amount of work it has to do in order to move against the direction of the field direction & then it spends energy on it , Now the energy which it possesses is only kinetic energy hence it is the equivalence which holds

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).